# Hide gray line inside HTML5 canvas

Tags: html, css, html5-canvas

Please see the jquery signature pad plugin:

http://thomasjbradley.ca/lab/signature-pad/require-drawn/

Notice the horizontal gray line inside the signature box:

[image]

I am trying to get rid of it but have not been able to do it. Here is the html element:

```
<canvas class="pad" width="198" height="55"></canvas>
```

And here is the css:

```
.pad {
  position: relative;
}

.current .pad {
  /**
   * For cross browser compatibility, this should be an absolute URL
   * In IE the cursor is relative to the HTML document
   * In all other browsers the cursor is relative to the CSS file
   *
   * http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2011/12/21/cross-browser-css-cursor-images-in-depth/
   */
  cursor: url("../Images/pen.cur"), crosshair;
  /**
   * IE will ignore this line because of the hotspot position
   * Unfortunately we need this twice, because some browsers ignore the hotspot inside the .cur
   */
  cursor: url("../Images/pen.cur") 16 16, crosshair;

  -ms-touch-action: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

This is driving me crazy. I've been 45 minutes in Chrome dev tools and cannot find what's making that gray line. Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In javascript you can set line width to 0 or its colour to "#fff".

For example: `$('.sigPad').signaturePad({lineWidth:0 })`

Useful documentation: http://thomasjbradley.ca/lab/signature-pad/#options

Comment: Good grief, throw an egg at my face. I glanced over those options before but didn't realize that was referring to the line in question. Thank you eu.vl.